# How to change the colour of a button when clicked on? (Vue)

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to get a button that changes its color when pressed on it. When it is pressed again, it should change back to its original color. What am I doing wrong?

The Button in my template:

```
<th><Button v-bind:class="{'white': !clicked, 'blue': clicked}" v-on:click ="!clicked" ></Button></th>


<script>
    export default {
        data: {

clicked: false
        }

    }

</script>

<style>
   .white {
       background-color: white;
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;  

   }
   .blue {
       width: 200px;
       height: 200px;
       background-color: blue;

   }


</style>
```

Comment: This is unrelated to your issue, but you should always make sure your data field is a function that returns an object. See [here](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should set `clicked` property explicitly by `@click="clicked = !clicked"`:

```html
<th>
  <Button
    v-bind:class="{'white': !clicked, 'blue': clicked}"
    v-on:click ="clicked = !clicked"
  />
</th>
```

Comment: Also, you can use ternary expression for setting a class dynamically:

`v-bind:class="clicked ? 'blue' : 'white'"`